# Как сохранить действие кнопки Button при смене ореинтации (а точнее сделать так что бы метод setAnswerShownResult) не "сбивался"

Tags: java, android, android-button

```
    mShowAnswerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_answer_button);
    mShowAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mAnswerIsTrue) {
            mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.true_button);
        } else {
            mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.false_button);
        }

            setAnswerShownResult(true);
    }
});

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // получаем ссылку на поле ввода текста
    // переменная которую сохраняем и под каким именем, чтобы потом прочитать
    savedInstanceState.putString(CHEAT_INDEX, String.valueOf(mAnswerTextView.getText()));
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

}
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mAnswerTextView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(CHEAT_INDEX));
       // setAnswerShownResult(true);

}

    private void setAnswerShownResult(boolean isAnswerShown) {
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, isAnswerShown);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
}
```

Comment: В чем проблема? Неужели так трудно дать подробностей.

Comment: при нажатии на Button запускается метод setAnswerShownResult при повороте экрана (Button как будто не нажимали)

Comment: не знаю просто как это грамотно обьяснить

Comment: Дополнительную информацию нужно добавлять в вопрос, а не в комментарии. Проблема, кстати, популярная, с ней сталкивались почти все и решение находится в интернете за пару минут.

Comment: Например: http://code.hootsuite.com/orientation-changes-on-android/

Comment: нету на русском такой статьи ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84278/discussion-between---and-).

Comment: @ЛевКурляндский, постарайтесь подробнее объяснить, что именно делает ваш метод? Какие-то поля заполняются текстом, или что-то другое. Если вы отредактируете вопрос, и добавите код с методом, ещё легче будет вам ответ дать.

Comment: Вы при повороте должны сохранять состояние mAnswerIsTrue, так как по его состоянию происходит что-то. И если вы не кликали (значит состояние false) и если кликнули и перевернули, значит состояние уже true .

Comment: Можете показать как бы вы сделали?

Comment: savedInstanceState.putBoolean(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN,mAnswerIsTrue); mAnswerIsTrue = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN);Это не помогло

Answer (score 0):

При повороте экрана активность останавливается и запускается снова, поэтому восстаналивается положение как после выполнения `onCreate()`. Чтобы восстановить текущее состояние экрана (с нажатыми радиокнопками, добавленными элементами и т.д.) нужно его предварительно сохранить. Например, так:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // переменная которую сохраняем и под каким именем, чтобы потом прочитать
    savedInstanceState.putString("ButtonText", mAnswerTextView.getText()); 
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mAnswerTextView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("ButtonText"));
}
```

Comment: @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mAnswerTextView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(CHEAT_INDEX));
            setAnswerShownResult(true);
            
    }

Comment: добавил свой метод в onRestoreInstanceState проблема частично решилась но он теперь вызывается при перевороте экрана а надо что бы именно при нажатии на Button

Comment: то есть если зайти в активити 2 случайно повернуть экран и вернуться то получиться сработает метод  setAnswerShownResult а надо именно при нажатии на Button

Comment: Я, честно говоря, уже не понимаю, что нужно и что происходит на самом деле. Отредактируйте вопрос так, чтобы было все понятно.

Comment: При нажатии на Button запускается мой метод, но при повороте экрана все сбивается.Я свой метод поместил в onRestoreInstanceState, но теперь он вызывается даже если просто повернуть экран, а по логике приложения он должен вызываться только после нажатия на Button

Comment: Зачем???? Не надо помещать свой метод никуда! Пусть будет там, где есть. Нужно просто добавить эти два метода в код.

Comment: Вы слова "отредактируйте вопрос" сознательно игнорируете или не понимаете, что я имею в виду?